# Displaying curl data, blank page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download json data using curl in PHP from companies house API.

Here is the example they provide that I'm trying to use:
https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/company/company_number/readCompanyProfile.html#here

The example:

```
curl -uYOUR_APIKEY_FOLLOWED_BY_A_COLON: https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/{company_number}
```

My code

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/01000000");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'curl -u8yUXrestOfmyApiKey:'
    ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(false == $result){
    echo curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
print($result);

?>
```

Using header:

```
'-u my_api_key:8yUXGgcHznjaNWnKpuKIJ7yv7HDvU_slH273GuF1'
```

I get 400 - bad request and with header in my code above I get nothing no errors blank page no data.

PS. There is a company with number 01000000 I've checked

Comment: `-u` is NOT a header. it's used to pass a `user:pass` pair to curl. you want `CURLOPT_USERPWD` instead.

Comment: @MarcB they say in the documentation that I should only pass username as API_key and leave the password blank.

Comment: irrelevant. `curl -u` is not a valid http header. you have use curlopt_userpwd. whether you provide an actual pw or not is up to you, but what you're doing is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuld add `CURLOPT_USERPWD`

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "YOUR API KEY"); #Add your api key`

Comment: the Companies House API takes the username as the API key and ignores the password, so can be left blank

Comment: Using `curl -u8yUXGgcHznjaNWnKpuKIJ7yv7HDvU_slH273GuF1: https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/01000000` in a command line it displays the json data..

Comment: @Alex..Hello sir..Can you please help me to solve this issue....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967017/how-to-trim-first-three-characters-based-on-the-first-letterexpression-before

Comment: @Alex , hi alex please check my probelm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900950/login-in-other-website-with-curl-in-php thankyou