# How to trim first three characters based on the first letter(expression) before inserting into the database

Tags: php, mysql

**my php file**

This is my code to retrieve data from database.

Here i need to remove first three characters based on the first expression(+) and followed by two numbers i.e(91). So totally i need to remove phone numbers which have +91 in database.
Can anyone help me regarding this.

```
    <?php
    session_start();


    $response = array();

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

    if(!mysqli_connect_errno()){

        $error_flag = false;

    $contacts = json_decode($_POST['contacts'], true);
    foreach($contacts as $contact){

            //$trimmed = $contact['phone'];

            //$title = str_replace("+91", "", trim($trimmed));
            // $prefix = '+91';
            // $str = $contact['phone'];
            // if (substr($str, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) 
            //     { echo $str = substr($str, strlen($prefix)); }


            $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (vault_no , name, phone, created_at)
            VALUES ('".$contact['vault_no']."', '".$contact['name']."', REPLACE('".$contact['phone']."','+91',''), NOW())";

                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                    echo "Successfully Saved";

                }else{
                    $response["error"] = true;
                    $response["error_msg"] = "INSERT operation failed";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
                    //}
    }

    }else{
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Database connection failed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

[image: this is my contact list in database]

Comment: you want to trim and store or get values and trim??

Comment: `remove` as in don't show, delete from database, update in database?

Comment: I have edited your code,just try now, it will work.

Comment: I tried it is not working.. i am getting insert operation failed

Comment: are you printed $phone_number, before saving in database?

Comment: try this query    $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (vault_no , name, phone, created_at)
VALUES ($contact['vault_no'], $contact['name'], $phone_number, NOW())";

Comment: again i have edited your code,just try once.

Comment: i tried in my local system, it's working fine for me. just print your values{$contact['vault_no'] and $contact['name']} before storing into database.

Comment: i am able to print the values now... but +91 is not removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`REPLACE()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) :

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.mobile,'+91','') as mobile
FROM YourTable t
```

Or if you want to change it in the database :

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.mobile = REPLACE(t.mobile,'+91','')
```

Comment: Much better approach. +10

Comment: Here is my updated code.. i am getiing insert operation failed.. when i try to insert the data.. can you please suggest me  whether the code is correct?

Comment: Does the data already exists on the table ? Maybe you need an update? I don't understand what you are trying to do..

Comment: yes i need to remove the +91 before inserting into the database

Comment: Then use my command, try this - REPLACE('$phone_number','+91','')  @PrajwalKM

Comment: I have updated my code.. please see it.. i need to remove +91 before inserting into the database

Comment: Hello sir.. Can you please suggest me where i am going wrong... I have updated my code... I am able to insert the data into database, but not able to remove +91...

Comment: @PrajwalKM But you are not listening to me, leave aside what the others said, use this : `REPLACE('".$contact['phone']."','+91','')` inside the insert statement, and remove the `STR_REPLACE` that you used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115375/discussion-between-prajwal-k-m-and-sagi).

Answer (score 1):

Remove it using `substr()`

```
$prefix = '+91';
$str = '+912345678765';// pass your mobile number here

if (substr($str, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
   echo $str = substr($str, strlen($prefix));
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://3v4l.org/pSFIm)

Comment: Here is my updated code.. i am getiing insert operation failed.. when i try to insert the data.. can you please suggest me  whether the code is correct?

Comment: echo $sql and paste what it return!!

Comment: Hello sir.. Can you please suggest me where i am going wrong... I have updated my code... I am able to insert the data into database, but not able to remove +91...

Comment: replace `$trimmed = $contact['phone'];

            $title = str_replace("+91", "", trim($trimmed));` with `if (substr($trimmed, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
   echo $trimmed = substr($trimmed, strlen($prefix));
}`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$code = "+919000044440";
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$code);
$phone_number = substr($number,2);
echo $phone_number;
```

Comment: Here is my updated code.. i am getiing insert operation failed.. when i try to insert the data.. can you please suggest me  whether the code is correct?

Comment: code is correct.and are you printed phone number before saving in databse?

Comment: comment these two lines of code and try              $trimmed = $contact['phone'];
            $new_trimmed = str_replace(" ", "", $trimmed);

Answer (score 1):

PHP `str_replace()` will work for you...

```
<?php 
$remove = '+91';
$phone_numbers = ['+919876543210','1234567890','+911234657899'];
foreach($phone_numbers as $number)
{
  echo str_replace($remove,'',$number)."\n";
}
?>
```

This will output:

```
9876543210
1234567890
1234657899
```

***[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://eval.in/593493)***

Comment: Here is my updated code.. i am getiing insert operation failed.. when i try to insert the data.. can you please suggest me  whether the code is correct?

Comment: replace your query `$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (vault_no , name, phone, created_at) VALUES ('".$contact['vault_no']."', '".$contact['name']."', '".$phone_number."', NOW())";` @PrajwalKM

Comment: i tried it is not working... i am getting insert operation failed

Comment: @PrajwalKM what data types you are using for these columns.. ??

Comment: i have added varchar

Comment: then you need to add qoutes for column `created_at` @PrajwalKM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115312/discussion-between-prajwal-k-m-and-manjeet-barnala).